# encfs does not mount folder

Tags: file, encryption, directory, mount

I have installed encfs to encrypt my directory and files and everything worked well when I installed encfs and configured it. I created two folders, one `/XDM/game` and second `/Private` and as encfs works I have to copy my files into /Private folder and this will sync all those files' encrypted version with `/XDM/game`. But when I restart my pc I have to remount `/Private` folder for that I am using the following command -

```
encfs ~/XDM/game ~/Private
```

But it returns me this error -

```
encfs ~/XDM/game* ~/Private
EncFS Password: 
fuse: mountpoint is not empty
fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option
fuse failed.  Common problems:
 - fuse kernel module not installed (modprobe fuse)
 - invalid options -- see usage message
```

help me with this error please. Thank you in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is 'In order to mount the directory you need to remove file from `/Private` folder and try mounting again with

```
encfs `~/XDM/game ~/Private`'
```

And long answer, after you configured encfs once you restart computer, you can see your folder `/Private` empty and to show the files you have to mount folder but if you copy any file in `/Private` folder and then try to mount then it will give you this error. So first delete the file you pasted/created after you restarted computer and then mount. It should work!

I have written a detailed article to help you understand better.

http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-encrypt-cloud-storage-files-folders-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in a similar scenario once when accidentally trying to write to the encrypted directory. Solved it by doing

```
encfs -o nonempty <encryptedDirPath> <decryptedDirMountPoint>
```

There are some repercussions to using the 'nonempty' option though. [More here](https://firmit.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/encfs-mount-over-nonempty-mount-point/).

If you are not able to unmount the decrypted directory after doing the above, you might need to delete the entry for your stash from Gnome Encfs Manager, in case you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem where it says that mountpoint is busy or not empty. so, I created another dir. in your case, you can do `mkdir ~/Private2`. and then, simply treat this as your new mountpoint.
`encfs ~/XDM/game ~/Private2`.